# I can see the behind texture through front one

Tags: uv

I wonder how to solve this problem

I can see through

this is what i did

1. import image as a plane
2. loop cut
3. extract

I'm sorry if my English is strange (T.T)

this pictures are captured in viewport

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the material of *Images as Planes* objects will have their *Show Backface* option enabled, disable it:

[image]

Comment: ohhh thank ypu sooo much!!! you save me!